# can json_encode($last_unopened_message_row) contain more than one parameter?

Tags: jquery, json

can i have getMessageDetails.php:

```
echo json_encode($last_unopened_message_row,$uniqueCode1,$uniqueCode2,$uniqueCode3);
```

and then in my getJSON call i have:

```
 $.getJSON('getMessageDetails.php', function (json,code1,code2,code3) {

 )}:
```

can i have it as above?
thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

what about

```
echo json_encode(array('lp'=>$last_unopened_message_row,'c1' => $uniqueCode1,'c2' =>$uniqueCode2,'c3' =>$uniqueCode3));
```

and json callback code

```
$.getJSON('getMessageDetails.php', function (json) {
    var code1 = json.c1;
    var code2 = json.c2;
    var code3 = json.c3;
    var lp = json.lp;
}):
```

?